# How to Get Max Price Based on Latest Date From group by query

Tags: mysql, sql

Example Records :

```
|name  |price |source|lastest_update|
|name A| 20.00|att   |04/10/2019 00:00:00|
|name A| 30.00|att   |04/11/2019 02:00:00|
|name A| 50.00|sprint|04/10/2019 01:00:00|
|name A| 40.00|sprint|04/11/2019 21:00:00|
```

Basically if we're using group by "group by name" the price that we'll get is the first one of the records, it's $20, but i want to get the max price based on lastest_update (date). So the results will be :

```
|name  |att_price|sprint_price|
|name A|  30.00  |  40.00     |
```

My query

```
SELECT 
MAX(WHEN source = 'att' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as att_price,
MAX(WHEN source = 'sprint' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as sprint_price
FROM table GROUP BY name;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `SELECT 
MAX(WHEN source = 'att' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as att_price,
MAX(WHEN source = 'sprint' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as sprint_price
FROM table GROUP BY latest_update DESC;` something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract `date` from your timestamp column `latest_update` and apply `max()` to get the latest date. Now, you can just add a where condition to filter rows only having this max date.

```
select name,
MAX(case WHEN source = 'att' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as att_price,
MAX(case WHEN source = 'sprint' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as sprint_price
FROM test 
where date(latest_update) = (select max(date(latest_update)) from test)
GROUP BY name;
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/43Uy7ocCKQRqJSaYHGcyRq/0

**Update:**

Since you need group by for each `source` according to individual source `latest_update` column, you can use the below SQL:

```
select t1.name,
    max(
        case 
            when t1.source = 'att' then t1.price
            else 0
        end
      ) as att_price,
     max(
        case 
            when t1.source = 'sprint' then t1.price
            else 0
        end
      ) as sprint_price
from test t1
      inner join (
        select name,source,max(latest_update) as latest_update
        from test
        group by name,source) t2
      on t1.name = t2.name and t1.source = t2.source
      and t1.latest_update  = t2.latest_update
group by t1.name;
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwBxizWooVG7AMwqKjewP/0

Comment: yup thank you very much, it doesn't work for some case, but i already improve based on your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @RizalYogiPratama Glad to help but can you let me know the case for which it fails, so that I can improve my answer?

Comment: technically it will not show if any last_date that less than max (last_update) date
Example: max last_date is "04/11/2019" from att, but there is some source that only updates once a month, ex: "04/01/2019" from sprint, this data from "04/01/2019" will not show.
basically, in every source data have different max last_update.

Thanks

Comment: @RizalYogiPratama Ok, but this wasn't pretty clear from your question as it's ambiguous. Anyway, what if 2 different sources having max dates had 2 different names?

Comment: ah i see, my bad. Still one the same name. but the price that we'll get should be the latest from the (last_update) in every source but in the same name.